# std::move and map assignment

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I am bit puzzled about how standard governs this case:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo & operator = (std::string xxx)
    {
        x = std::move(xxx);
        return *this;
    }

    std::string x;
};

std::map<std::string, Foo> bar;

std::string baz = "some string";

bar[baz] = std::move(baz);
```

Can compilers produce code so that `baz` will be moved *before* it's used to initialise and get reference to element in `bar` (to initialise `std::string xxx`)? Or is this code safe and there's no *undefined behaviour*?

Comment: It's not UB, but not guaranteed to work, either.

Comment: See [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ef8993192148d84) simplified version of your code. `std::map` and the assignment operator don't need to be involved for this to occur, and their presence doesn't change the underlying problem with the code.

Comment: @Mankarse, yes, indeed, everything can be boiled down to this case

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hell no. The expression is, yes, equivalent to

```
(bar.operator[](baz)).operator=(std::move(baz))
```

But there is no guaranteed order between the evaluation of `(bar.operator[](baz)).operator=` - formally, the *postfix-expression* designating the function to be called - and the evaluation of the initialization of the *argument* to `operator=`, which is what moves from `baz`.

In fact, [this asserts on GCC](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HdUuiyODgQUdkVWu):

```
std::map<std::string, Foo> bar;
std::string baz = "some string";
bar[baz] = std::move(baz);
assert(bar.count("some string"));
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I thought myself, just wanted a confirmation from someone else.